# form buttons where only one can be selected

Tags: jquery, forms

Hi i have the following page coded but the form is not right. i need the bottom section 3x buttons that say gas / electricty / both to only be able to select one at a time.

url: http://www.comparebusinessenergy.co.uk/april/

i understand i can achieve this by jquery with something like this:

but i cant work it out for the life of me

```
$('ul li').click(function(){
      $('ul li.selected').removeClass('selected');
      $(this).addClass('selected');
      return false;
});
```

Comment: Why not use radio buttons for this type of use case?

Comment: do you get an error? what part is not working? the remove class or the add class or both? Is your page building w/o javascript errors,( ! ) in the bottom left corner?

Comment: just to throw this out there... i don't know what browser your developing in but in IE on my settings/resolution the site is barely readable... everything is overlapped.

Answer (score 2):

Try this for size:

```
$('#gas,#electric,#both').click(function(){
  $('#gas,#electric,#both').removeClass('on').addClass('off');
  $(this).addClass('on');
  return false;
});
```

I think you were getting your selectors wrong. The way this is working is that you select using css style selectors, then operate on the jQuery objects that are created.

Comment: Thanks billy, i think we are very close with this one although it hasnt worked.

Comment: I'm not crazy about hard coding the ids, but Billy is right, your selectors are wrong. I'd change the selector to a css class so if you ever add or remove a button, change names etc you simply apply the selector class rather then having to also updating the JS.

Comment: hi matto0 thanks for the input, although im not quite sure what you mean. do you mean code it so input is the class and then .on .off is a seperate class to the input

Comment: @Roy Hey, sorry didn't notice you had replied. Yes that's what I mean. The inputs will all have the same class say "servicebutton" and then your jquery will add the on/off toggle classes. So on Billy's example it would be $(".servicebutton").click(function(){$(".servicebutton").removeClass... this isn't necessary by any means, it just cleans up your code a bit and makes it more maintainable.

Comment: I agree with @matto0 about the class thing - that is what classes are for in any language, to group objects that share a similarity. Id's should be used to uniquely identify objects. Makes things easier to maintain, and easier for other people to read etc...

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to be toggling between the `on` and `off` classes. Just change `$(this).addClass('selected')` to:

```
$(this).toggleClass('on');
$(this).toggleClass('off');
```

Make sure that the correct class is set initially.

Comment: yea thats right, but i cant get the jquery to toggle them clases. i must be doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

$('ul li:selected').removeClass('selected');

try that

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('ul li').click(function(){
      $('ul li').removeClass('selected');
      $(this).addClass('selected');
      return false;
});
```